# Store api JSON response in a variable

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a simple web scraper:

```
var url = "sadasd";

var obj;

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => obj = data)
  .then(() => console.log(obj))
```

My question is, why can't I access the `obj` variable outside the fetch with something like `console.log(obj);` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: It's likely because any code that's run that needs `obj` needs to _wait_ until `obj` has a value.